# jsf richFaces treeNode expanded - how to call a method with argument?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, wildfly

Facelet works fine in tomcat8, but in wildfly8 (jboss8) I get stack trace on first click of expand tree node icon.

```
<jsf.version>2.1.13</jsf.version>
<org.richfaces.version>4.3.7.Final</org.richfaces.version>
```

following facelet fragment:

```
<rich:tree  id="tree" value="#{categoryBean.categoryNodes}" var="categName"    prependId="true" selectionType="ajax" toggleType="ajax" >

    <rich:treeNode  prependId="true" 
        expanded="#{carelineBean.shouldExpandTree(categName)}" 
        toggleListener="#{carelineBean.expandNode(categName)}"  >
            <h:outputText value="#{categName}" />
    </rich:treeNode>

</rich:tree>
```

in jboss at first click on expand icon I get stack trace:

[Server:server-one] Caused by: javax.el.**PropertyNotWritableException**: /editCall.xhtml @88,156 **expanded="#{carelineBean.shouldExpandTree(categName)}"**: Illegal Syntax for **Set Operation**
[Server:server-one]     at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:136)
[Server:server-one]     at org.richfaces.component.AbstractTree.broadcast(AbstractTree.java:301)
[Server:server-one]     ... 50 more
[Server:server-one] Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation

the next click successfully expands tree branch without stack trace

The doc of expanded states:
*Determines if this tree node is expanded. When **EL expression** used, it should use request-scoped variable with name defied in **tree attribute 'var'** which points to current node.*

How can I decide if node should be expanded in method of backing bean, method must know the current node which should be expanded? Why is it working right in tomcat, but not in wildfly ?

According to 
 Makhiel: **RF 4.3.x is not supported on WildFly**.

Where can I find this information, RF is jboss product and is not supported in jboss8 ?!

Is RF supported in jboss 7.x ?

How can RF be best replaced ? I need sth like rf:tree and rf:treenode.

Is RF 3.x supported in jboss 7.x, wildfly 8 ?

Comment: RF 4.3.x is not supported on WildFly.

Comment: Please see my new questions concerning your comment.

Comment: Have you tried `<f:attribute name="categName" value="#{categName}" />` inside the `<rich:treeNode />`?

Comment: @Makhiel I don't declare RF as provided in pom.xml, it is placed in my war in WEB-INF/lib, afaik RF is a tag library, so either sth is nok with RF or with wildfly. How can an application server not support tags ?

Comment: @Alexandre I haven't, I will try tomorrow, today I have a day off.

Comment: The tags are backed by objects that exist on server side. There have been some significant changes to the server side of things when it comes to WildFly. Some things might still work, some will definitely not.

Comment: I have rewritten carelineBean.shouldExpandTree(categName) to categName.shouldExpandTree, and this is working

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten *${carelineBean.shouldExpandTree(categName)}* to *${categName.shouldExpandTree}*, and this is working;